# User login on clean page

Tags: login

My first post on UX, I hope this is the correct place...

I have a very *clean* website with a variable page width. The home page consists solely of buttons that lead to certain parts of the site. Currently, the button to log in is also positioned on this page. When logged in, this button changes to an account-button where the user can view his or her account details.

Now, I'm guessing this isn't really user-friendly, that you can't access your account information directly from any page. How can I solve this?

I've thought of following solutions, each with its own issues:

- full bar on top of page - issue is I don't really have anything other than the login-button/username to show
- Tab on top of page that slides down - issue is that my page has a variable width. For example the home page is around 200px wide, though other pages can be up to 80% of the screen width
- a tab on left/right side of page - doesn't seem very user friendly

What's the best solution?

Here are two images of how my site looks at the moment. As you can see, I'm truly a disaster in UI, so other remarks/ideas are welcome as well of course.

[image: home screen when hovering over <code>Stats</code> with the mouse]
[image: Home screen after clicking the slideToggle <code>Login</code> to show login form]

Answer (score 1):

With the screens you have shown, I don't think it's required to having a/c info access from all pages. The user is not likely to need to access this so often.

The closest example I can think of is Apple's iCloud.com. It has similarities to what you are doing.

iCloud homepage after login:
[image: iCloud homepage after login]

iCloud once an app is launched (no access to a/c info):
[image: iCloud once an app is launched]

Comment: Didn't think of that! Looks clean. Where would you advise to place it though, in the top right corner or perhaps at the maximum of the page ever (80% of the screen)? Unfortunately I don't have an iCloud-enabled iDevice, so I can't check the website itself, but top right at 80% seems like a good option. Might look a bit off when on the smaller pages like the screenshots